# React js cannot read property 'id' of undefined for the property of API Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a React application that searches and brings up pictures and videos of the topic I searched using Pixabay API. However, I am encountering "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" when I try to call id of the API call that I fetched. What can I do to fix this error?

API Call:
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 801826, pageURL: "https://pixabay.com/photos/pug-dog-pet-animal-puppy-cute-801826/", type: "photo", tags: "pug, dog, pet", previewURL: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/08/15/02/pug-801826_150.jpg", …} ...

**App.js**

```js
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Board from './board/board';
import ImageSearch from './imageSearch/imageSearch'

const API_KEY = "19435337-59a77b980b37e8c813d079adb"



class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    images: []
  }

  handleGetRequest = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const searchValue = event.target.elements.searchValue.value;

    const URL = `https://pixabay.com/api/?key=${API_KEY}&q=${searchValue}&image_type=photo&per_page=7`
    
    const request = await fetch(URL);
    const response = await request.json();

    this.setState({ images : response.hits });
    console.log (this.state.images)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ImageSearch handleGetRequest={this.handleGetRequest}/>
        <Board image={this.state.images[0]} />

      </div>

    )
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

**Board.js**

```js
import './board.css';
import React from 'react';
  
const Board = (image) => {

  return ( 
    <div>
      <div key={image.image.id}>
        <input type="image" className="board__image" src={image.image.largeImageURL} alt={image.image.tags}></input>
      </div>
    </div>      
  )
}

export default Board;
```

Comment: On which line it gives error

Comment: On line 8 of Board.js @MaheerAli

Answer (score 1):

The result does not exist until the API call is completed.  You need to check if it exists before rendering the markup in your `Board` component:

```
const Board = (image) => {

  return (
<> 
    { image && <div>
      <div key={image.image.id}>
        <input type="image" className="board__image" src={image.image.largeImageURL} alt={image.image.tags}></input>
      </div>
    </div> }    
</> 
  )
}
```

Or any other solution that ensures the image exists should work.

Comment: when I console.log (image) at Board.js, it gives me the API call image: {…}}image: {id: 801826, pageURL: "https://pixabay.com/photos/pug-dog-pet-animal-puppy-cute-801826/", type: ...}

Comment: It cannot exist until the fetch call is completed, but you are using it immediately. That's why it's undefined.

Comment: Then, why does the console.log() gives the values although the fetch call is not complete?

Comment: It will exist after the fetch call is completed, but not before. Try using the code I posted.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'largeImageURL' of undefined

Comment: Post the structure of your image object in the question, you could be accessing it incorrectly. Why are you accessing ```image.image.prop```, shouldn't it be ```image.prop```?

Comment: the image object structure is in the App.js

Comment: I used image.image.prop because image.prop keeps giving me "undefined" in the console.